# Proof of limit of polynomial function.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, polynomials

This exercise is used many places. Recall that a polynomial of degree $n$ is a function of the form

$$P(x) = a_n*x^n + a_{n-1}*x^{n-1} + ....+ a_1x + a_0,$$

where $a_j$ are real numbers for $j = 0,\ 1,\ \cdots,\ n$ and $a_n$ is not zero.

a) Prove that if $0^0 = 1$, then $$\lim_{x \to a}x^n = a^n$$ for $n = 0,\ 1,\ \cdots $ and $a$ is a real number.

proof:

when $n = 1$, we have $P(x) = a_0 + a_1*x$.

When $a_1 = 0$ there is nothing to prove.

Otherwise, given $\varepsilon > 0$, set $\delta = \varepsilon/|a_1|$.

If $|x - a | < \delta $, then $$|P(x) - P(a)| = |a_0 + a_1*x -( a_0 + a_1*a)| = |a_1||x_a| < |a_1|*\delta = \varepsilon.$$
Thus $P(x) \to P(a)$ as $x \to a$.
So $$\lim_{x \to a} x^n = [\lim_{x \to a} x]^n = a^n.$$ 
Can someone please tell me if this is fine? Any feedback/hint would be very helpful. I am having trouble with  $0^0 = 1$. I could not even understand how to use it.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq] to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. In addition, [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/8348) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good.

Comment: I think you are a little confused about the notation. You aren't supposed to prove the theorem for degree 1 polynomials, you are supposed to show that the limit of $x^n$ is $a^n$ as $x$ approaches $a$.

This is easy to show with limit rules. The reason why you have $0^0 = 1$ is because $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} x^0 = \lim_{x\rightarrow a} 1 = 1$, so you know that the result is consistent for all possible real $a$.

Comment: I don't know if you refer to calculus limit rules. I need to prove it by definition. I can't use simple calculus.

Answer (score 0):

I think Bruce Zheng refers to the product rule of limit. Another way is to use definition, $|x^n-a^n|=|x-a||x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}a+ \cdots +a^{n-1}|$ when $n \geq 2$. Then when $x$ is closed to $a$, by triangle inequality, we can expand the second term and show it's bounded. Then you can select $\delta$ based on $\epsilon$. After that, it suffices to consider $n=0,1$.

The reason why $0^0=1$ is just like what Bruce mentioned in the comments.